# Compilation error with default command line argument value

Tags: command-line, go, default-value

As I try to take a command line argument of type uint64, when I am setting default value to a valid unsigned 64 bit number, I am getting following compilation error.

**Compilation Error:**
Expression type mismatch, the expected type is uint64 less... 
It highlights the number 5000 here indicating that's not an acceptable value.

**Code:**

```
var golferInstance uint64 

flag.Uint64Var(&golferInstance, "inst", 5000, "Golfer Instance ID, this should be Globaly Unique ")
flag.Parse()
```

I don't see anything wrong with above declaration, then why is the compilation error ??

What am I missing here? (i believe must be something silly that i fail to make out)
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Go are you using? Seems to work fine on the playground..

Comment: go version go1.2.2 linux/amd64

Comment: How are you compiling this? If you're using an IDE maybe try compiling with the go tool directly?

Comment: Yes, looks like some issue with IDE(IntelliJ 13.1.2) background compilation process. Using 'gd' build tool I built and it worked. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The Inspection type in the [go-lang-idea-plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/) has some issues regarding certain type Mismatch detection.
See [issue 348](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/348) (which is supposed to be solved in latest version of that plugin)

You can un-select that inspector.

> In the interface it's called '`Highlight mismatched types`', I believe this is the one.
>   The message from inspection is: '`Expression type mismatch, expected type is ...`'
>
> It also seems it has problems in detecting that '`1 * time.Second`' in the construct '`time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)`' is a proper '`Duration`' type and it tries to fix it like this '`time.Sleep((time.Duration)(1 * time.Second))`'.

Falling back to command line, and/or making sure all components are up-to-date (golang IntelliJ plugin, Go itself), can help.